# The Alignment on top Right and top Left are not exactly Align on the top of the page | flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have two RaisedButton and I want to make them at the top of the page for (add and cancel) and it aligned at the top of the page but one of them it's gone down a bit in the middle of the page as you can see here [app Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXmWi.jpg)

and one more question,How can I solve this problem?
[TextFormFeild issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drpOr.jpg)

My code of the cancel and add Button:

```
  Widget addCancelButton(
      String Buttontext, textAlign, textColor, backgroundColor) {
    return Align(
      alignment: textAlign,
      //Alignment.topRight,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 79,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(Buttontext,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
              )),

          color: backgroundColor,
          textColor: textColor,
          //Colors.purple[900],
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }






   final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right:20),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: addCancelButton(
                        'add',
                        Alignment.topRight,
                        Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
                  ),
                  addCancelButton(
                      'Cancel',
                      Alignment.topLeft,
                      Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 80,
                  ),
                  modalBottomSheet(
                    userInput: widget.title,
                    buttonFeild: 'Title',
                    buttonHinit: 'Ex: My friend birthday',
                    buttonKeyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    butonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  modalBottomSheet(
                    userInput: widget.emoji,
                    buttonFeild: 'Emoji',
                    buttonHinit: 'Enter an emoji',
                    buttonKeyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    butonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  modalBottomSheet(
                    userInput: widget.datePicker.toString(),
                    buttonFeild: 'Date',
                    buttonHinit: 'Mar 19,2022',
                    textEditingController: textEditingController1,
                    buttonKeyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                    IconButtonFuncation: () => datePicker(),
                    butonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                    icon: Icons.calendar_today,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  modalBottomSheet(
                    userInput: widget.TimePicker.toString(),
                    buttonFeild: 'Time',
                    buttonHinit: '9:00 am',
                    textEditingController: textEditingController2,
                    IconButtonFuncation: () => timePicker(),
                    buttonKeyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                    butonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                    icon: Icons.access_time_sharp,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  modalBottomSheet(
                    userInput: widget.notes,
                    buttonFeild: 'Notes',
                    buttonHinit: 'To Do list',
                    buttonKeyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLine: 5,
                    butonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My code of the TextFormFeild:

```
 modalBottomSheet(
              // userInput: notes,
              buttonFeild: 'Notes',
              buttonHinit: 'To Do list',
              buttonKeyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              butonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
              contentPaddingText: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 100.0),
            ),
```

__

```
TextFormField(
          keyboardType: widget.buttonKeyboardType,
          controller: widget.textEditingController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: widget.IconButtonFuncation,
                icon: Icon(
                  widget.icon,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
            prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            ),
            contentPadding: widget.contentPaddingText,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: widget.buttonHinit,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: widget.butonColor,
            //Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
          validator: (String value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Feild is Required';
            }

            return null;
          },
          onSaved: (String value) {
            //  widget.userInput = value;
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Concerning your buttons

You have placed your buttons in a `Column`, wausing them to be placed bellow each other. You should use a `Row` instead like so:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    addCancelButton('Add'),
    addCancelButton('Cancel')
  ],
)
```

#### Concerning your text field

Here it's because of the text field internal padding that you use:

```dart
/// GOOD
contentPaddingText: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 10.0), // Reduce the horizontal padding

/// BAD
contentPaddingText: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 100.0),
```

Comment: I changed it to Row and there was an exception thrown "RenderBox was not laid out"

Comment: This is because of what is above the row. I don't have enough information to help you but if you read the error entirely it should help you to fix it.

Comment: This is the exception (Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#19e63
relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT

Another exception was thrown: Updated layout information required for
_RenderScrollSemantics#905ad NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate semantics.

Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Future already completed) I have added the Expanded and ListView but still same error

Comment: Yes it's about constraints and Expanded placement. However I can't currently help you with only the code you shared. I need more information, ideally in a form that I can execute.

Comment: I have edit the post to include the whole code